# Core Data - How to track subset of set of entities

Tags: ios, objective-c, entity-framework, core-data

I'm new to core data and looking for guidance on what is likely a simple issue:

I have a set of entities and each entity may or may not belong to a certain set. I want to be able to retrieve those which belong to the set in the most efficient manner possible. How should I set this up?

Let's make this a little more concrete. Pretend the entity at issue is a Person. I have many different Person entities in my data store. Some of those Persons work for Apple. I often want to retrieve only those Persons that work for Apple. How should I set this up?

Based on my naive understanding of Core Data, I have two options. (1) Create another entity called AppleEmployees with a to-many relationship to Person and add Persons to the AppleEmployee entity when necessary. Or (2) Create an attribute on the Person entity that tracks that Person's employer, and filter the fetch request accordingly.

Note: I'm not worried about tracking many different employers (to continue the metaphor). A Person either works for Apple or doesn't; my critical inquiry is to be able to fetch the Apple employees. :)

So my question boils down to: are these methods viable? if so, which is the best? is there any better method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this with Company and Persons managed objects. Then given a company named "Apple":

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Company"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@", @"Apple"];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSArray *results = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
Company *apple = [results lastObject];
NSSet *applePeople = apple.employees;
```

The set applePeople is the set of all Person managed objects with the employees relationship to the company with name "Apple" (There is no error checking here... add some if you use this.)

**Company managed object:**

Attribute "name", NSString *

Relationship: employees, to many, to Person, NSSet *

**Person managed object:**

Attribute: "name", NSString *

Attribute: "employeeNumber", NSString *

Relationship: company, to one, inverse of employees relationship in **Company**

And you can vary this. You might consider contractors that work for multiple companies simultaneously and have the company relationship be to many also.

Comment: Thank you for your quick but thorough response. Your answer reinforces what I'm learning about Core Data. :) Let me ask this question, though: Assume that the only result sets we EVER care about are those Persons who work for Apple and those Persons who do not work for Apple--(I guess my metaphor was not suited well to emphasize this)--would that change your implementation in any way?

Comment: I would still make a Company object with a name. Anything can happen - if there was another division spinoff (like Newton) you might want to include those employees in your data even if they officially were at another company. And keeping it generic makes it more likely you can apply what you do here to other projects. I don't think making this more specific to one company would appreciably improve efficiency.

Comment: "I don't think making this more specific to one company would appreciably improve efficiency." You got right at my concern. Thanks for your insights!